# Can i write this group by query without group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've written query to find HOw many orders placed by each customer?
I would like to now can i write same querying without using Group by clause?
using somekind of subquery and join.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, count(si.CustomerID)
from Customer c LEFT OUTER join SalesInvoice si
ON si.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP by c.CustomerID
```

Comment: why's that? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, count(si.CustomerID) OVER(PARTITION BY c.CustomerID)
from Customer c LEFT OUTER join SalesInvoice si
ON si.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```